# C++ string length error exception

Tags: c++, string, runtime-error

I have a text file that i'm reading from and contains the following:

```
file "transform.in" .....:
10
@--------@
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
@---------
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
---------@
(end of file)
```

the following code that i use creates a segmation fault:

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    ifstream input("transform.in");
    ofstream output("transform.out");
    int n;
    char arxiko[10][10] = {0};
    string teliko = "", line;

    int main()
    {
        input >> n;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            input >> arxiko[i];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        input >> line;
        teliko += line; // here, in the first iteration the segmation fault occurs
    }
```

If a line contains 9 characters instead of 10, there's no problem, but with 10 it crashes!
Also, i did some test with the string += operator and i could append a string bigger than 10 characters succesfully, but why do i fail in this?

Comment: 10 characters, with a terminating 0, makes 11 bytes.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `char**` as well as `std::string` together?

Comment: @gargankit     because this is the segment of the code that produces the error. In the rest program i need the char**-strings to have 2 index values (arxiko[i][j]).

Comment: the problem though is with the += command

Comment: The problem is that arxiko has exceeded its bounds so it  has corrupted some parts of any variable that is declared after it.  If you change the lower bound to 11 as suggested by others, that will stop the corruption.

Comment: Cannot reproduce..., thought you should use `char arxiko[10][11]`.

Comment: thank you very much, i changed arxiko bounds and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string in C++ is always terminated by a `NULL` character, written as `'\0'`. Since the input file contains 10 characters per line, you might try something like this:

```
char arxiko[11][11] = {'\0'};
```

Comment: The place where the problem surfaces is not necessarily where it was caused. You have use of a standard library class and hand-written memory management with raw arrays; the problem is pretty obviously the latter.